# Show QMainwindow in the middle of the screen

Tags: pyqt4, qmainwindow

I want show my project main window in the middle of the screen . when i call "self.show()" then the window show in the middle of the screen .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would recommend against trying to force a window position on your users and let the system's window manager decide where it should go. If you really insist on positioning it yourself (perhaps you are programming for a kiosk), you can find [some information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382537/setting-qmainwindow-at-the-center-of-screen) in a previous question on stackoverflow.

A slightly more elegant calculation for doing this is [discussed here.](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/14772-how-to-show-window-in-the-center-of-the-screen)

When doing this calculation, it is important that it is done at the correct time, after Qt has resized everything and just before it is shown on screen. One method that might help is to [create a one-shot timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465647/qt-how-to-capture-event-indicating-that-all-gui-elements-are-ready/5465799#5465799) and do the screen positioning in the slot for the timer.

Answer (score 8):

I know you have already solved it, but I make this answer for those who have the same question. I post it mainly because you asked for pyQt and the other answer is for Qt (C++).
I found a workaround here: https://bashelton.com/2009/06/pyqt-center-on-screen/

Is so simple and works perfectly, I transmit it..

```
class ExampleWindow (QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self, parent=None):
        '''constructor'''
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 650, 550)
        self.setWindowTitle("My Example Application")
        self.centerOnScreen()

    def centerOnScreen (self):
        '''centerOnScreen()
Centers the window on the screen.'''
        resolution = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        self.move((resolution.width() / 2) - (self.frameSize().width() / 2),
                  (resolution.height() / 2) - (self.frameSize().height() / 2))
```

Good luck!

Comment: Is there a way to specify what monitor this will appear on? I am working with 2 monitors set up.

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtGui' has no attribute 'QDesktopWidget'`

Comment: This is a great answer. Useful, elegant. It worked great for me!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Pyqt5:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

qtRectangle = self.frameGeometry()
centerPoint = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
qtRectangle.moveCenter(centerPoint)
self.move(qtRectangle.topLeft())
```