# Why QMainWindow is in top left corner while QDialog is in center position?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qmainwindow, qdialog

I don't understand why by default a `QDialog` is placed in center position and a `QMainWindow` in the top left corner?

**Example code:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Dialog")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    dialog = Dialog()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I would prefer a `QMainWindow` in center position by default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show QMainwindow in the middle of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710824/show-qmainwindow-in-the-middle-of-the-screen)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyQt center window on active screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20243637/984421)